# Steps to create entity framework to Pervasive database

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, odbc, pervasive-sql

I want to create Entity model using Visual studio Wizard for pervasive tables.

I am using VS2012 and Pervasive Software v 11 (having ADONET4.0).

When I try to add data source, ODBC is not appearing in 'Data Source'. Since ODBC is only a Programming interface, so there is no data provider that VS expects.

If anybody have done this before, could you please share me the steps?

I found the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb163974.aspx. But it is very confusing.

Thanks in advance,
Best regards,

Answer (score 3):

user,

First if you are using ADO then ODBC will have nothing to do with it.  Also I don't have 2012 but this is what I did in 2010, I don't think there is a lot of difference.

You need to download and install the PSQL-SDK-Dotnet4.1-11.xx.xxx.xxx_en-US.exe file.  This will get you the Pervasive Provider for Entity Framework.  Then you can follow along a tutorial like this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.

As I understand it right now Pervasive only supports EF 4.5 but I've gotten EF 5.0 to work.  I have not tried EF 6.0.  You will probably need to use NuGet to install EF 5.0 to the project instead of 6.0.  To do that click on View->Other Windows->Package Manager Console and then in the console window type:

PM>install-package entityframework -version 5.0.0.0

You can read more about this in this post: [How to install EntityFramework 5.0 (and other older versions) from NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956925/how-to-install-entityframework-5-0-and-other-older-versions-from-nuget)

I know this is 6 months late but hope it helps.

Comment: After installing the PSQL-SDK-Dotnet can i expect it to show up in the Entity Data Model wizard?

Comment: After some digging in the sdk docs i found that the PSQL client needed a repair in order for this to work!